Issue with Authentication Using Cookies in Production
I'm encountering difficulties with authentication using cookies in my production environment. While everything works smoothly on localhost, I face issues when attempting to authenticate in the production environment. Specifically, the problem arises during the creation of a new journal entry after successful login.
Technology Stack:
I'm using the MERN stack for my project.
Express Backend Setup:
// CORS configuration

const corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
        }
    },
    credentials: true,
};

// JWT token generation

function generateAuthToken(user) {
    if (!user || !user._id || !user.email) {
        throw new Error('User object is missing required properties');
    }

    return jwt.sign(
        {
            userId: user._id,
            email: user.email,
        },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET
    );
} 

// Login user function

exports.loginUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        if (!email) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Invalid email',
            });
        }
        if (!email.includes('@') || !email.includes('.')) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid email format' });
        }

        if (!password || password === 'google' || password === '') {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Invalid password',
            });
        }

        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'No user found' });
        }


        const isPasswordValid = await comparePassword(password, user.password);
        if (!isPasswordValid) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid credentials' });
        }

        const token = generateAuthToken(user);

        const { password: newPassword, ...userWithoutPassword } = user._doc;

        res.status(200)
            .cookie('AuthToken', token, authTokenCookieOptions)
            .json({
                message: 'User logged in successfully',
                user: userWithoutPassword,
            });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
};

// Function for processing journal entry creation

exports.create = async (req, res) => {
    const { title, content, mood } = req.body;


    const token = req.cookies['AuthToken'];

    if (!token) {
        console.log('Create: No token found');
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
    }

    if (!token || !mood) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'Missing required fields',
        });
    }

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        const userID = decoded.userId;

        const journalEntry = new JournalEntry({
            userID,
            title,
            content,
            mood,
        });

        const data = await journalEntry.save();
        res.json(data);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message:
                err.message ||
                'Some error occurred while creating the Journal Entry.',
        });
    }
};

Frontend Request:
// Function for creating a journal entry 

export const createJournalEntry = async (content, mood) => {
    if (!mood) {
        throw new Error('Mood is required');
    }
    const title = content?.[0]?.content?.[0]?.text || 'Untitled';
    const newContent = JSON.stringify(content);
    const body = {
        content: newContent,
        title: title,
        mood: mood,
    };
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('/journal-entries/create', body, {
            withCredentials: true,
        });
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.response.data);
        throw error;
    }
};

Upon successful signing, the user is directed to create a new journal entry. However, in the production environment, this process fails, resulting in an Unauthorized response and the error message "Create: No token found." I see the cookie in the developer tools with an expiration of one month.

The signing process is completed successfully.
The failure occurs when attempting to create a new journal entry after signing in.
The error indicates that no token is found during the creation of a journal entry.

I need help in identifying and resolving the issue causing the authentication failure during the creation of a new journal entry in the production environment. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Perhaps my blog post here might give you some clues about how to debug cookies problems in your browser https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/ (look at the end of it)
